# repaint and reflow with ng-repeat angular directive

Tags: angularjs, web-performance

I am a newbie in **angular js**.
`ng-repeat` directive iterate over the model and as soon as the model changes (adding/deleting the values) then the `ng-repeat` directive update itself.

If this is true, then it will force the repaint and reflow operation in the browser for all the values in the model object, which is a costly operation from the performance point of view.

Comment: Please tell what is your question ?

Comment: how much performance will it cause if i update the respective model quite frequently

Answer (score 0):

It all depends in the number of variables involved and thus, in the number of watchers.

Usually,  withwin 10k watchers you should be fine. I would be very cautious going anywhere above 10k watchers because you can get some trouble (yes, your machine running chrome >= 40 *will* be fine, but your users with IE9 will not).

You can, however, reduce the total number of watchers of your views by using bindonce (you can follow this wonderful guide [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/)) or some other strategies (use less ng-if by wrapping your views in a unique container, for example).